# Rspec / Capybara non-determinism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, capybara

I have an Rspec test with code like this:

```
visit root_path(cc: coupon.code)

using_wait_time 5 do
  page.should have_content 'Welcome!  You have applied coupon ' + coupon.code
end
```

Basically, the user can hit our root path with a coupon code, and that code should get set in a cookie and confirmed with visual feedback.

This test works if I run it by itself:

```
Finished in 36.81 seconds (files took 6.69 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```

But if I run it as part of my whole suite of tests, I get errors:

```
  1) Setup sets coupon
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content 'Welcome!  You have applied coupon ' + coupon.code
       expected #has_content?("Welcome!  You have applied coupon foo") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/setup_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/setup_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The only way that can happen is if the cookie isn't getting set.  Does anyone know why running the test by itself vs running it as part of the whole suite would make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this somewhere before your test (right before your visit, or even in a background block):

```
page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
```

Normally this is called between tests but this should help further diagnose what is going on with your spec.

Comment: I tried that using the show_me_the_cookies gem, and it didn't have any effect.  Note that using browser.manage only works with Selenium.  If you're using webkit, that will throw an error.